# Codeigniter URI Not Working - 404 Error

Tags: database, codeigniter, uri

I have searched around for examples but i am getting an odd result

i wish to have the following occur /pages/1 URL to return from the database the markup column of row 1 of the pages table.

controller

```
    public function index()
        {
            $id = $this->uri->segment(2);
            $content = $this->page->specificMarkup($id);
            $this->template->set('nav', 'support');
            $this->template->set('content', $content);
            $this->template->load('master', 'contact');
        }
```

model

```
    public function specificMarkup($id)

        {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('pages', $id);
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row->markup;
        }
```

it works when i specifically set the $id, but now returns a 404 error when i try to use segments, the user guide gives me the impression that this should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question for others that run into this issue.

1.

the model needs to be

```
public function specificMarkup($id)

    {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('pages', array('id' => $id));
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->markup;
    }
```

2.
Their does need to be an entry in the routes.php

$route[ 'pages/(:num)' ] = 'pages/index/$1'

This is so codeigniter knows where to direct the traffic